# sequence satisfies liminf condition

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

is there any positive bounded sequence $\left\lbrace a_{n} \right\rbrace _{n \geq 0}$, that is $0 < a_{-} \leq a_{n} \leq a_{+} < + \infty , \forall n \geq 0$, such that
$$ a_{n} - a_{n+1} \geq 0 , \forall n \geq 0 \textrm{ and } \liminf_{n \to + \infty} \left( a_{n} - a_{n+1} \right) > 0 . $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No ! If $a_n-a_{n+1}\geq 0$ then the sequence is decreasing and thus convergent. Therefore $$\liminf_{n\to \infty }(a_n-a_{n+1})=\lim_{n\to \infty }(a_{n}-a_{n+1})=0.$$